# I have "Reports.Read.All" permission but still cant get request of this :

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to use [this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-1).

It is about getting activity time of users. I saw that I need Reports.Read.All permission to send this request. Then my maneger admitted this permission for me. However I still cant get a return :
[image]

As you see, it gives this error on the photo.

Comment: You have added link to list user. Not to specific report.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

When I ran the same query in Graph Explorer, I'm getting **`CORS`** error like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
```

**Response:**

[image]

So, I tried to do the same via **Postman** by registering one Azure AD application and added **`Reports.Read.All`** permission without granting consent like below:

[image]

I generated access token via **Postman** with parameters like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:appID
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:client_secret
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call query, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant **admin consent** to **`Reports.Read.All`** Application permission like below:

[image]

I generated access token **again** after granting admin consent.

When I used **that token** to call the query, I got response successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you granted admin consent to **`Reports.Read.All`** of **Delegated** type, you will still get **403 Forbidden** error.

So, make sure to add **`Reports.Read.All`** of **Application** type and grant **admin** consent while using client credentials flow.